# Adding 3 numbers and subtracting with another number calculation in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project for my employer I am trying to create a jQuery function that adds up 3 numbers and then subtracts the total numbers to give me a usage total.

I have just used the same function `updateDue()` and changed the id's so they were different to each reading time.

I am new to jQuery and will be going to uni in September to learn all of this. I wanted to start early.

Any advice would be great.

Edit in JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jameshanna95/w2y42rjd/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=w2y42rjd#&togetherjs=UslvN4QcQ2

```js
function updateDue() {
  var sday = parseInt(document.getElementById("sday").value);
  var snight = parseInt(document.getElementById("snight").value);
  var sew = parseInt(document.getElementById("sew").value);
  // to make sure that they are numbers
  if (!sday) {
    sday = 0;
  }
  if (!snight) {
    snight = 0;
  }
  if (!sew) {
    sew = 0;
  }
  var ansD = document.getElementById("stotal");
  ansD.value = sday + snight + sew;
}


// Final Readings 

function updateDue() {
  var fday = parseInt(document.getElementById("fday").value);
  var fnight = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnight").value);
  var few = parseInt(document.getElementById("few").value);
  // to make sure that they are numbers
  if (!fday) {
    fday = 0;
  }
  if (!fnight) {
    snight = 0;
  }
  if (!few) {
    few = 0;
  }
  var ansD = document.getElementById("ftotal");
  ansD.value = fday + few + fnight;
}
var ansD = document.getElementById("usage");
ansD.value = stotal + ftotal;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So why are the function names duplicated?

Comment: i need to add all day night and ew for start and final and subtract to give a difference. i am new to jQuery each  functions would be 3 separate  calculations.

Comment: Having two functions with the same name just means it will only take on the latest definition. The first updateDue won't ever be used because it's been overwritten

Comment: so is the "updatedue" a id or reference?

Comment: Your `function updateDue()`. They cannot be the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you had `updateDue` declared twice (which you later changed), there wasn't much issue with the rest of code, just some missing `.value`s.

```js
function startreading() {
  var sday = parseInt(document.getElementById("sday").value);
  var snight = parseInt(document.getElementById("snight").value);
  var sew = parseInt(document.getElementById("sew").value);
  
  if (!sday) {
    sday = 0;
  }
  if (!snight) {
    snight = 0;
  }
  if (!sew) {
    sew = 0;
  }

  var ansD = document.getElementById("stotal");
  ansD.value = sday + snight + sew;
}


// Final Readings 

function finalreading() {
  var fday = parseInt(document.getElementById("fday").value);
  var fnight = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnight").value);
  var few = parseInt(document.getElementById("few").value);
  
  if (!fday) {
    fday = 0;
  }
  if (!fnight) {
    fnight = 0;
  }
  if (!few) {
    few = 0;
  }  

  var ansD = document.getElementById("ftotal");
  ansD.value = fday + few + fnight;
  var ansD = document.getElementById("usage");
  start = !parseInt(stotal.value) ? 0 : parseInt(stotal.value);
  final = !parseInt(ftotal.value) ? 0 : parseInt(ftotal.value);
  ansD.value = start + final;

}
```

```html
<h1>
Start Readings 
</h1>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Day</label>
  <input type="text" name="day" class="form-control" id="sday" onchange="startreading()">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Night</label>
  <input type="text" name="Night" class="form-control" id="snight" onchange="startreading()">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">EW</label>
  <input type="text" name="ew" class="form-control" id="sew" onchange="startreading()">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Total</label>
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="stotal">
</div>
<hr>
<!-- Final Readings -->

<h1>
Final Readings 
</h1>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Day</label>
  <input type="text" name="day" class="form-control" id="fday" onchange="finalreading()">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Night</label>
  <input type="text" name="Night" class="form-control" id="fnight" onchange="finalreading()">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">EW</label>
  <input type="text" name="ew" class="form-control" id="few" onchange="finalreading()">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">Total</label>
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="ftotal">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label for="exampleInputText">usage</label>
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="usage">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. worked perfect. Now I know how to complete the full calculations. It going to help me example. Thank you again!

Comment: mark as answer when you can so it helps other people